# getting wrong path after sign in rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

My route file is as follows:

```
  devise_for :admins
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', :as => 'rails_admin'
```

I have an admin model as follows:

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

end
```

After an admin signs in the route is wrong

```
http://localhost:3000/admin/s/sign_in
```

And I get the following error message:

```
Model 'S' could not be found
```

How can I fix this route?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to change my route to match the following:

```
 devise_for :admins
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admins', :as => 'rails_admin'
```

and tell Devise that I am using admins and not users as the model

Answer (score 0):

Why your routes have `/s` after `admin/`, I think it must look like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/admin/sign_in
```

To make sure run `rake routes`